# Timing control for windows on RX 350

Tags: timing, window, control

I own an RX 350 and was wondering where the timing of window controls is located on the computer board. By timing I mean when you simply tap the console switch the window or sunroof will open incrementally as opposed to holding it down for a little longer will fully open or retract whatever window you're interesting in controlling. What governs that timing: S/W or H/W or both? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there actually a problem you are trying to fix? If so, what's going on? Most auto-down features can either be done by the switch in the door or by the body control module (BCM) or a combination of both.

Comment: No way we can answer this, only the car engineer knows..

Comment: There currently isn't a problem with the windows but I've been curious regarding the timing issues associated with either incremental movement or "full" opening or closing motions. Thanks for taking the time to respond!